# {{ domain }} becomes example.com on local pc

Tags: python, django

I am learning to send mails with django, but I get into this issue, that it returns `http://example.com/` instead of `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`

The code that sends the mail and generate the link is following (I've added comments on the two lines I suspect being the reason):

```
views.py
# Send activation E-mail
        current_site = get_current_site(self.request)  # Either this line
        mail_subject = 'Activate your Penge account.'
        message = render_to_string('emails/activation-mail.html', {
            'user': user,
            'domain': current_site.domain,  # or maybe this line
            'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
            'token': default_token_generator.make_token(user),
        })
        to_email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
        email = EmailMessage(
            mail_subject, message, to=[to_email]
        )
        email.send()
        return HttpResponse('Please confirm your email address')
```

```
activation-mail.html

{% autoescape off %}
Hi {{ user.username }},

Please click on the link to confirm your registration,
http://{{ domain }}{% url 'accounts:activate' uidb64=uid token=token %}

If you think, it's not you, then please ignore this email.
{% endautoescape %}
```

How would I correct this as the function should get the domain using. Ideally I'd be able to define this in `settings.py` for when I deploy my application.

Thank you in advance.

EDIT! Added e-mail template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have configured the django [sites](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/sites/) framework. So instead of `get_current_site` use the `request.get_host()`

```
'domain': request.get_host(),
```

Or you can change your site domain from the django admin panel to `127.0.0.1` from `example.com` and `get_current_site(request).domain` will work

Comment: There we go! Wasn't aware of this. Thank you so much!